# Is there a precise relationship between ``Geometric Functional Analysis" and high-dimensional probability/information theory?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, soft-question, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-probability

The 2009 course on GFA by Roman Vershynin `(https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/GFA-book.pdf)` introduced the subject with this line on the course page, "Geometric functional analysis studies high dimensional linear structures. Some examples of such structures are Euclidean and Banach spaces, convex sets and linear operators in high dimensions. A central question of geometric functional analysis is: what do typical n-dimensional structures look like when n grows to infinity?"

Now in recent times there have been `high-dimensional information theory` courses like this, http://www.stat.yale.edu/~yw562/teaching/598/index.html and Vershynin has himself written a (very famous!) book on `high-dimensional probability` http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf

- Is it possible to see the contents of the above new courses and books as new and modern forms of GFA? Are there any specific famous results which embody such a relationship?

I do feel that there is a strong overlap among these 3 but I would like to know if there is a well-established technically precise view of the relationship between them.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a "well-established technically precise view of the relationship"?

Comment: As in if experienced researchers in this field have evolved any standard way to relate these 3 view points. If there are famous theorems that people refer to as the point of evolution of GFA into these new subjets or point of contact between these.